# DMVPN dual tunnel interface on one physical interface + crypto map

Tags: cisco, ipsec

Please help me to resolve the following issue.
I've got a router which is used for ipsec tunnels (crypto maps). It has public ip address.

Now I need to make from it DMVPN HUB. Also I need to create two tunnel intefaces for DMVPN clouds on one physical interface with public ip address. At the same time I need to keep crypto maps wich already exist.
For every tunnel inteface I created crypto ipsec profile, crypto isakmp profile and crypto keyring.
In configuration of crypto keyring I have the following string: match identity address 0.0.0.0
After configuration I mentioned that problem with crypto maps occured. I've seen that some crypto sessions (show crypto sessions) have reestablished to my Tunnel interface.
Please let me know how to separate my crypto isakmp policies for crypto maps and crypto isakmp profiles for using dmvpn.

Also I would be very obliged if you give me a link to an article where the same topology example is configured.
The main questions is how to separete policies for crypto maps and crypto isakmp profiles.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I'm new here but i'll give you my design strategy for this scenario -

1. keep the single source public interface for your crypto map and your dmvpn clouds - check out the isakmp profile feature :) it matches exactly what you want nicely.
2. The pro solution to this problem - create a public loopback interface, make sure the internet can ping it (all networks routeable). Source each dmvpn network from its own dedicated public loopback interface. Packets will come in PAST the crypto map on the public physical interface route "across" the loopback and to your dmvpn.

interface tunnel1
tunnel source loop99